# How to add data type to an A tag

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add a data type to an A tag  by using jQuery

here is the HTML

```
<div class="asset-manager-button">
    <div>
        <a class="uk-position-cover"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the jQuery i thought would work

```
$('.asset-manager-button .uk-position-cover').appendTo('data-uk-scrollspy-nav="{smoothscroll: {offset: 90}, closest:'li'}"');
```

and here is what i would like to achieve

```
<div class"asset-manager-button">
  <div>
    <a class="uk-position-cover" data-uk-scrollspy-nav="{smoothscroll: {offset: 90}, closest:'li'}"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may not see the effect with jquery `data` method thought it actually does(it is invisible when you inspect the tag but you can still retrieve them with jquery `data` method)

try another method  `attr("data-uk-scrollspy-nav","its value")` also works. It is visible so you can inspect and see.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the `data()` method, like this:

```
$('.asset-manager-button .uk-position-cover')
    .data('uk-scrollspy-nav', "{smoothscroll: {offset: 90}, closest:'li'}");
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the inof, however, i dont seem to be able to get it to work, i've addded the script above, but it doesn not append to the A tag, any suggestions?

Comment: @user2513528. I don't understand: in your OP you said you want "to add a data type to an A tag", so it's what my answer does. Why do you talk about _append_ to the A tag? To append is to have a new tag created as sub-tag of the target tag: nothing common with adding a data type to it.

Comment: hi, sorry i may have used the wrong word to describe, i have edited the Original question to give clearer expectations of out come

Comment: Note that using `data()` in its setter form will not set a DOM attribute, but instead alter jQuery’s internal set of data attributes for that element. If you actually want to change the DOM attributes, you must use `attr()`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I totally agree. But I proposed the jQuery solution because the basic code showed already used jQuery.